# Does this sentence/statement imply something not obvious to a non english speaker

Tags: meaning

In a video game someone made me an offer for an item. He wrote

> 1 Cred. You cant refuse because it's 1 cred more than what you currently have.

("Cred" being a currency in game)

I, a german, told him that his statement is wrong. His offer of ONE is not more than what i currently own in the video game. He kept arguing that i had to see it as an addition to what i "currently" own. He kept pointing out the "currently" part and insisted that his statement was correct.

At some point i wondered if the sentence implied something different to an english speaker than it does to someone who just translates it.

I read it as "I offer 1 and 1 is more (right now) than your millions." which is not true. He had to assume that i owned millions or at the very least more than zero.

(there is a chance he was trolling but nontheless, i am curious)

Comment: The person is being sarcastic. They implied that the item is valueless, meaning 0 Cred in value.

Comment: In a following discussion he kept insisting on his statement being correct, no trace of sarcasm

Comment: Maybe *sarcasm* isn't the right word. *snarky* is more precise. To expand a bit more, regardless of the item's value, it is worth exactly 0 cred to that person. Therefore, they are willing to pay you 1 Cred more than what they think it is worth - 0 cred. The person is trying to screw you over, hence their persistence. Ignore them, you'll get a better deal later on.

Comment: Maybe i should clarify, we both knew it was a joke offer. And it wasnt really about the price.

Comment: Upon further inspection, I now get what you were trying to say. The person did not imply that "I offer 1 and 1 is more (right now) than your millions". They meant: Your item is worth 0 Cred to me, regardless of how expensive it actually is. I'll pay exactly 1 Cred, which is 1 Cred more than the 0 Cred I think it is worth. Therefore, I paid you 1 Cred in exchange for something that is worthless. Because I'm willing to give you something of value (1 Cred) for something without value (0 Cred), my offer is too good to be denied.

Comment: I dont think he tried to mock the price as it was obvious to us both that we didnt need the item. He really just wanted to make a snarky comment.

Comment: @vth So you are interpreting "what you currently have" as the value of the *object*, and not NikkyD's net worth in Creds? That is not how I read it but it makes sense as a possible interpretation. (So, arguably, it is implying something not obvious even to an English speaker!)

Comment: Obviously the person saying his offer was "one cred more than what you currently have" means *No matter how many creds you already have, you don't have **this** one*. It's all a matter of [***fungibility***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fungible) (which in these days of [NFTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-fungible_token) should be more familiar to everyone).

Answer (score 4):

I can only interpret "it's 1 cred more than you currently have" as meaning that the antecedent of **it** is the **1 cred** referred to in the introductory sentence "1 Cred." If **it** is to be more than you currently have, that implies that you currently have (or the other player thinks you have) zero.

Even if the other player interprets **it** to mean "what you will have *after* the transaction" then there is no reason you "must" accept. Because if, as you say, you currently have 1 million creds (or even 100) then having one more is not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have 879762 Creds right now.

He was saying that, if you were to sell that item to him, you would then have 879763 Creds. Meaning, that you would have 1 more than "currently".

This is always going to be true. What he was saying was basically the linguistic equivalent to this mathematical equation `x < x + 1`, where `x` is whatever money that you currently own.

Although, I'm fairly certain he was joking, too. Still, he's technically right.

Comment: But he wrote "it IS" one more, not "it will be"

Comment: @Nicky: 101 *is* 1 more than 100, not *will be*.

Comment: but the "it" refers to the 1 cred. See the answer of James Random

Comment: Nicky: what is your point? 1 cred *is* more than 0, just as 879763  creds *is* more than 879762. "1 cred would be 1 more than you have now" is (or would be) another way of phrasing the thought; *will be* cannot be right.

Comment: I see what you mean now. He definitely worded that sentence poorly. Still, I think from context, he clearly meant to use "it" just like James Random said.